# is there any way for solidity 0.4.24 get bytes data from call

Tags: solidity

I am trying to follow this trick.

https://blog.polymath.network/try-catch-in-solidity-handling-the-revert-exception-f53718f76047

For solidity version 5 all works and I can do this:

```
(bool success, bytes memory returnData) =
                address(token).call(...)
```

For solidity version 4 I can do only this:

```
 (bool success) =
    address(token).call(...)
```

If I am trying get returnData in v4 I get this err

> TypeError: Not enough components (1) in value to assign all variables
>   (2).

is there any way to get returnData for Solidity v 4 ? Without double call?

I need this data for case not to make a double call when I need to check the view function, this can be called or not on contracts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is only possible in version 5 and newer

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.0/050-breaking-changes.html